# Proper way of launching google-chrome in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, subprocess

I am trying to launch google-chrome from python using subprocess, but without success so far. Basically I have a bash command like this:

```sh
TMP_PROFILE_DIR=$(mktemp -d -t chrome.XXXXXXXXXX)

google-chrome \
  --no-first-run \
  --disable-gpu \
  --disable-translate \
  --disable-default-apps \
  --disable-extensions \
  --disable-background-networking \
  --disable-sync \
  --metrics-recording-only \
  --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update \
  --disable-setuid-sandbox \
  --user-data-dir=${TMP_PROFILE_DIR} \
  --remote-debugging-port=9222 'about:blank'
```

which runs just fine. I see a new chrome window with tab `about:blank` and no profile. I wanted to reproduce this in Python:

```py
import tempfile
import subprocess

CHROME_FLAGS = [
    '--start-maximized',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--disable-translate',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-extensions',
    '--disable-background-networking',
    '--disable-sync',
    '--metrics-recording-only',
    '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--mute-audio',
]

direc = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()

args = ['google-chrome'] \
    + CHROME_FLAGS \
    + ['--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--user-data-dir=%s' % direc.name, "'about:blank'"]

process = subprocess.Popen(args,
    close_fds=True,
    shell=True
)

code = self.process.wait()
```

Window appears (but not the same as in bash case) and the only thing I get is this message:

```
[24663:24680:0714/004126.068170:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] Waited 5 ms for network service
Opening in existing browser session
```

I cannot even kill the window from Python. Any idea how to properly launch google-chrome and terminate it from Python?

Comment: I experience the same issue in BASH.  Want to capture the correct PID, then watch for when it closes....then close a different process.  What a pain.  Also tried finding a way to force chrome to run in the foreground then subsequent functions can happen after the window closes.

Answer (score 0):

I use `selenium` for web crawlers.

```
from selenium import webdriver
website = "https://www.google.com/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # Use .Chrome() for Chrome
driver.get(website)
```

I am sure you will need to get `geckodriver` into path.

Comment: While this answer is correct, you should know that google chrome makes a chromium driver. Using that instead of Firefox will automatically take you directly to the google page.